# how to compile cython code

Tags: python, cython

I want to compile my code. I want to write my own cpp file that calls functions from other libraries.

my cpp code

```
//my_vl.h
int my_vl_k(int normalized_feat_set, int k){}
```

my pxd file

```
#my_vl.pxd
import libc.stdlib

cdef extern from "my_vl.h":
    int my_vl_k(int normalized_feat_set, int k)
```

I know I won't need the .h file and the .pxd file for now but it's good practice, and if you can help me on how to include that would really help as well.

my cpp file:

```
//my_vl.cpp    
extern "C" {
  #include <vl/random.h>
  #include <vl/generic.h>
  #include <vl/kmeans.h>
  #include <vl/mathop.h>
}

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>


int my_vl_k(int normalized_feat_set, int K){
  int r = 5;
return r;
}
```

my pyx file:

```
#my_vl.pyx
cimport my_vl


cdef extern from "my_vl.cpp":
    int my_vl_k(int, int)
```

my setup file:

```
#setup.my_val.py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


sourcefiles = ['my_vl.pyx', 'my_vl.cpp']
ext_modules = [Extension("my_vl", 
                          sourcefiles,
                          include_dirs = ['/path/to/vlfeat-0.9.20'],
                           libraries = ['vl'],
                          library_dirs = ['/path/to/vlfeat-0.9.20/bin/glnxa64/']
                          )]

setup(
  name = 'my_val app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

error I get is:

```
python setup.my_val.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
skipping 'my_vl.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'my_vl' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/path/to/vlfeat-0.9.20 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c my_vl.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_vl.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/path/to/vlfeat-0.9.20 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c my_vl.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_vl.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_vl.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_vl.o -L/path/to/vlfeat-0.9.20/bin/glnxa64/ -lvl -o /mnt/disk2/work/visual_clusters/my_vl.so
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_vl.o: In function `my_vl_k(int, int)':
/path/to/my_vl.cpp:45: multiple definition of `my_vl_k(int, int)'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_vl.o:/path/to/my_vl.cpp:45: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
```

Not sure what I have to do

Answer (score 0):

In my_v1.h you should use header guards:

my_v1.h:

```
#ifndef MY_V1_H
#define MY_V1_H

// your function decl.

#endif
```

Comment: i change my h file to 

#ifndef MY_Vl_H
#define MY_Vl_H

int my_vl_k(int normalized_feat_set, int k){};

#endif

still I get the same error. I dont think my setup file knows about my h file as I did not include it or pass it down to it.

Answer (score 0):

You provide the definition of `my_vl_k` in your header file (`{}`). Instead write

```
int my_vl_k(int normalized_feat_set, int k);
```

(replace the curly brackets which provide a useless empty definition with a semi-colon which just says that the function exists).